# How to assign a value to a date depending on it in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using PostgreSQL and want to create a function and use it in the same query. The function that I want to create should do the same as the following python function:

```
def get_season(dia):

    season = (abs(dia.year) % 100) + (1 if dia.strftime('%m-%d') >= '10-01' else 0)
    return season
```

Giving a datetime, the function returns the last two digits of its year, or the previous one plus 1 if the date is greater than October the first, for example:

input = `'2017-3-5'`  -> output = `17`

input = `'2019-11-1'` -> output = `20`

The problem is that I don't know what functions use for doing that in PostgreSQL.

Currently, I'm using the following code, but throw errors:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION get_season(dia, datetime) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
    MOD(EXTRACT(year FROM dia), 100) + 
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dia) >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    END $$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

    SELECT date_column, get_season(date_column)
    FROM my_table
```

The error throw is: `(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) dia type doesn't exist`

Comment: Don't put a comma between the name of the variable and the type. You wrote `dia, datetime`, remove the comma. You use comma to separate name-type pairs if you have multiple arguments: `create function x(name varchar, age int, birthdate date)`

Answer (score 0):

The following should do this:

```
create or replace function get_season(p_input date) 
  returns integer
as
$$
  select case 
           when extract(month from p_input) > 9 then extract(year from p_input)::int + 1
           else extract(year from p_input)::int 
         end % 100
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

The condition `extract(month from p_input) > 9` checks if the date is in October or later and returns the next year's value.

However, I would strongly recommend not to use two-digit years.

Comment: @Á.Garzón: `get_season(dia, datetime)` defines a function with two (unnamed) parameters. The first is required to be of type `dia` the second of type `datetime` - neither of those data types exist in Postgres. Why didn't you use the function definition from my answer?

Comment: Yes yes, I was in a bit of a hurry. I've changed that to ```get_season(dia date)```, because it throws me that datetime is not a valid type. Now, the problem is the type of data in my date_column...However, when I SELECT it as usually, python tells me that is datetime.date type...

Comment: @Á.Garzón: your column might be a `timestamp`. Check the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table. Or the table definition in the SQL client you are using

Comment: I've just checked it and the type is date.

Comment: This seems to be a python problem then, because the function [works with plain SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9ec680f67dadbef04252424cb95a4ecc)

Comment: I've tested exactly your example and now the error is: ```'dict' object does not support indexing ```, which usually is a problem related with wildcards, but it isn't being used here.

Comment: I keep trying...thanks you anyways. A last question, what exactly means the $$ operator?

Comment: @Á.Garzón: see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: @Á.Garzón do please consider to ask a new question - what started out here as "how do I extract a month from a date" became a completely unrelated "what does $$ mean on pgsql", via other unrelated queries of data types and python coding errors. SO is intended to be like a wiki of "one question, N good answers" rather than a tech support service of "ask one question then drag people through every unrelated problem that happens throughout the course of the day". People will help, becaus eits what they like to do, but it should be asked as N questions, not N edits to one question

Answer (score 0):

The postgres EXTRACT function will pull part of a date out, so I'd thus imagine you can make something like:

```
MOD(EXTRACT(year FROM yourdate), 100) + 
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM yourdate) > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The first gets the date as two digits, the second gets 0 or 1 to add depending on the month

ps; I'm not sure I would call such a function "get_season", there being 4 seasons a year etc - perhaps "get_academic_year", but this is entirely contextual I'm sure.. Just a note of what an unknowing third party assumed when they saw the word "season"

Comment: See my comment on your question